# What's the input in the build function in tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to initialize the parameters of an RNN cell. For that I think I have to build the layer first. So then I tried to build the layer by using the build method in BasicLSTMCell, but it gave an error `int object has no attribute value`. Please help me or give me another method to initialize the weights and biases.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf   
my_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units = 128) # 128 is the hidden dimension which is a hyperparameter to be choosen by you
# Note you have just declared the LSTM cell till now, they haven't been initialized.
# Do something with the LSTM
with tf.Session as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # This line is necessary for the LSTM's parameters (The Matrices and Bias vectors) to be initialized
```